# Jquery mobile application white patch showing on orientation change in android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, screen-orientation

I'm developing a crossplatform Jquery mobile application wherein on orientation change its shows white patch.following is the code i've used for orientation change.

```
window.onorientationchange = function () {
    setTimeout(changeOrientation, 200);
}

changeOrientation :function() {
    //here goes my code for screen display on orientation.
}
```

so I was not able to find how to resolve this white patch on orientation change.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: some screenshots would be nice :) and what version of jQM are u using?

Comment: this white patch stays just for a sec and disappears so taking a screen shot is not quite possible and i'm using jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js

Comment: what `background-color` does the `body` of your HTML have?

Comment: Have applied an image for background

Comment: searching on internet,I found this code
window.onorientationchange = function () {
    setTimeout(changeOrientation, 200);
}

changeOrientation :function() {
$(window).trigger("throttledresize");
    //here goes my code for screen display on orientation.
}

integrated this code into my orientation change method but still no success.

Comment: what phone are u testing this on?

Comment: I have tested it on low resolution android phones as well as on samsung grand

Answer (score 0):

I suspect .. you are doing this in a webview inside your Android app, and that your application does not handle orientation change.

Either that, or the browser has the same issue, or your webpage is flawed.
A normal jquery webpage should not have this problem, a website just automagically resizes itself then the browser window (or device orientation) changes. Does your page have CSS or JS code that sets element width values?

What browsers have you tried on Android?
Does the latest Android Chrome have the same problem?